# Invalid order by orientation

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

In my database I have the columns `id`, `uid` and `data` and I would like to sort `id` by `DESC`.

```
$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(FormInputs::class)->findBy(['uid' => $uid], ['id', 'DESC']);
```

If I use the second parameter (`['id', 'DESC']`), I get the following error:

> Invalid order by orientation specified for App\Entity\FormInputs#0

Why am I getting this error?

Comment: Do you see the difference? `['id' => 'DESC']`

Comment: @gp_sflover oh yes, now I see! Thank you :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try Passing that like

```
$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(FormInputs::class)->
findBy(
  ['uid'=>$uid],
  ['id'=>'DESC']
);
```